# Trying to get {\mathcal n}, and I get the backslash \

Tags: fonts, mathcal

I am trying to get `{\mathcal n}` within an equation, but instead I get the backslash (`\`).

I would be satisfied with a smaller version (say, 75%) of `{\mathcal N}`, or some other smallish scriptish version of "n", but I haven't seen a suitable simple font.

Here is a sample line:

```
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{n}=n_{0}+n.
\end{equation}
```

I am using

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,prb,aps,epsf,amsmath,amssymb,showpacs]{revtex4}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
```

Comment: Welcome! You likely need a font that has calligraphic lower case letters (example: [newcomputermodern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad5dU.png)). Unless you want to scale the N but that won't look good.

Answer (score 4):

The classical TeX uses the font cmsy10 for calligraphic letters. It is seven-bit font (128 characters per font). The cmsy10 font combines uppercase calligraphic letters with other math symbols and there is no lowercase calligraphic letters. There is the symbol "setminus" at the position of the ASCII n, i.e. the code 110.

Note that the Unicode declares the "Mathematical script small n" at the position U+1D4C3 and Unicode math fonts provide this character.

Answer (score 1):

The `revtex4` class has been obsolete for several years and is still distributed just for back compatibility. The current one is `revtex4-2`. Also, the `epsf` option might have been useful for `revtex4`, but it's unknown for `revtex4-2` (and for good reasons, as `epsf.sty` is only for documents written before 1995).

Now the problem. You need to use a math font that has lowercase calligraphic letters.

The simplest method is to borrow the STIX2 font.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,prb,aps,amsmath,amssymb,showpacs]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[cal=stixtwofancy]{mathalpha}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{A}\mathcal{N}\mathcal{a}\mathcal{n}$
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{n}=n_{0}+n.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]